# Get the raw http request/response message in java

Tags: java, httprequest, httpresponse

I want the raw http request and response when sending an http request using java.
is there any way to do it without writing it manually? maybe adding tee with InputStream in the middle to capture it? or other solution?

i am currently using java.net.http library:

```
HttpRequest httpsRequest = getHttpsRequest(url, parameters, method, headers);
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(httpsRequest,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString(UTF_8));

String rawHttpMessage = ?
```

raw http message for example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Oct 2010 23:26:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
Last-Modified: Sun, 26 Sep 2010 22:04:35 GMT
ETag: "45b6-834-49130cc1182c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 12
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Hello world!
```

[request and response http message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf65f.png)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.html `httpResponse.body()` ?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way. You could maybe cheat something in for HTTPS by providing your own SSL socket factory that wraps a real one and "syphons" off the request/response. I suspect using some third-party HTTP client could make this simpler.

Comment: Out of curiosity: **why** do you need this? For almost every use case the pre-parsed headers are more useful. If you told us the underlying problem you're trying to solve, we can maybe find an alternative approach (see https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: i need the raw http request to save each api http request that i am sending and the responds. this way the user could see the exact message that sent and recived.